# iOS: Enterprise Server architecture

Tags: iphone, .net, objective-c, ios

For iPhone and iPad i.e iOS development

1. Is there a specific server platform required to setup for
   development and deployment enterprise apps?
2. Is there a specific architecture for this purpose? If so which one
   since we are will be calling windows web service.
3. Is an application development server required or can we use an
   ordinary pc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server doesn't need anything special to distribute apps, we have it working fine on an ordinary Linux box. All you need is:

- a URL to an XML file that describes the app
- a URL to a png image for your app icon (for use while the app is being downloaded)
- a URL to a .ipa file containing the actual app.
- some kind of authentication to ensure these URLs aren't publicly available (this could just be a VERY long random string inside the URL, perhaps one that changes regularly).

All of that can be done on any ordinary HTTP web server, without even any dynamic pages.

Some other enterprise features, such as push notifications, will require a programming language that can do some fairly low level network stuff. We've got that working fine with PHP, I'm not sure what would be the best language to work with on Windows.

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you will need a Mac OS X based workstation for writing and compiling the app(s) you're working on. This cannot be done on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but given that the web service is a windows web service does that mean that mmy back end would need to be set up differently in order to work with ios. i.e. what would the communication protocol be for me to consume the web service. If you know of any framework to assist with this process it would really be helpful.

Comment: The "communication protocol" is just plain HTTP. You don't need anything special, just a normal static web server. If you want more specific details you'll need to ask more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

1) No
2) It's up to you.  For instance you could feed XML or JSON equally on your windows web service.  The way you call your server from the client on the app is your decision.  Typically driven by a URL.
3) No, an application development server is not required.  You can use an ordinary PC if you wanted.  I've done this multiple times for testing sure.  But for a large audience of course I would recommend something large like a linux server and not a "home PC".

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further on your second answer regarding the architecture? What would be your recommended method or better yet a supported method for enterprise apps. Thanks for your reply.